# HasManyThrough Relations includes a Pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a **Module**, **Question** and **Category** model.

```
Module hasMany Questions. (1 to Many)
Question belongsToMany Categories. (Many to Many)
```

For a given **Module**, I would like to access only the **Questions** where **category_id = X** .

I'm not sure what the most efficient way of doing this is. Can I do it through a HasManyThrough relation between Module and Category? Or do I have to create a loop? Or do it through a raw SQL query?

**Update**:

This SQL query seems to work. However, I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution?

```
SELECT id
FROM questions
INNER JOIN category_question ON questions.id = category_question.question_id 
WHERE category_question.category_id = X and module_id = Y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using this

```
 Question::with(['module','categories'])
   ->join('category_question','category_question.question_id','=','question.id')
   ->where('category_question.category_id','=','X')
   ->where('questions.module_id','=','module_id')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it doesn't seem to work unfortunately, I think because the Questions table doesn't have a category_id (as it is related through a pivot table).

Comment: Thank you! Had to make a few minor tweaks to it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
Question::with(['model','categories'=>function($query){
    return $query->where('category_question.category_id',$category_id);
}])->get();
```

hope this works.